# How to create a button that opens a drawer and use the same to close it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a Windows 95 style Start button in a bottom bar in my app in Flutter. The idea is, you click the button it shows a pressed style button, and when you click the button again the drawer closes and returns to the first unpressed image.

I've tried this:

1. Create another file with a GestureDetector that when you press the image it changes and lasts 100 milliseconds, at least to have the animation
2. Import it to the main file and enclosed that Widget in a gesture detector that when you use onTap: it opens the drawer

But it didn't work.

By the way I know I can use ElevatedButton, but the problem is I want the button to be the exact PNG of the windows 95 Start button in its pressed and unpressed state, I'm using 2 PNGs for that.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InteractiveImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image1Path; // Path to the first image
  final String image2Path; // Path to the second image
  // Optional height for the image

  const InteractiveImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.image1Path,
    required this.image2Path,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InteractiveImage> createState() => _InteractiveImageState();
}

class _InteractiveImageState extends State<InteractiveImage> {
  bool _isImage1Shown = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isImage1Shown = !_isImage1Shown;
        });
        // Schedule the switch back to the first image after 1 second
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _isImage1Shown = true;
            });
          }
        });
      },
      child: _isImage1Shown
          ? Image.asset(
              widget.image1Path,
            )
          : Image.asset(
              widget.image2Path,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

/////////////////////////

MAIN PAGE

```dart
// ONLY THE BOTTOM BAR SECTION.....



//Bottom Bar
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: GradientBoxBorder(
            width: 3,
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [blanco, negro]), //i created the colors of the app in a file apart
          ),
        ),
        //bottom bar decoration
        child: BottomAppBar(
          height: 100,
          color: colorBase,
          child: Row(
            //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                },
                child: const InteractiveImage(
                    image1Path: 'assets/images/start1.png',
                    image2Path: 'assets/images/start2.png'),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/search.png'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i used Listener on the Custom Widget with onPointHover, and it works, but i still have no idea of how to make the button pressed and unpressed open and close the drawer

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky, since the drawer open-close state is stored by the Scaffold using an internally created `DrawerController` object.

You could provide to your scaffold a callback functions using `onDrawerChanged` which triggers a `ChangeNotifier` every time the open-close state of the drawer changes.  Wrap the Scaffold in a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to make the notifier available to the child widgets using context. If you prefer you could also pass it as an argument in the constructor of those widgets.

```dart
/// Notifier for changes in the drawer open/close state.
class DrawerChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  DrawerChangeNotifier();

  void change() => notifyListeners();
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  _MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final DrawerChangeNotifier _drawerChangeNotifier = DrawerChangeNotifier();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<DrawerChangeNotifier>.value(
      value: _drawerChangeNotifier,
      child: Scaffold(
        onDrawerChanged: (_) => _drawerChangeNotifier.change(),
        floatingActionButton: const InteractiveImage(
          iconOpen: Icons.menu,
          iconClose: Icons.close,
        ),
        drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then modify you button to listen to changes and read the current drawer state.

```dart
class InteractiveImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData iconOpen;
  final IconData iconClose;

  const InteractiveImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.iconOpen,
    required this.iconClose,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListenableBuilder(
      listenable: context.watch<DrawerChangeNotifier>(),
      builder: (ctx, Widget? child) {
        final scaffoldState = Scaffold.of(context);
        final bool open = scaffoldState.isDrawerOpen;
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (open) {
              // The drawer is open, so close it.
              scaffoldState.closeDrawer();
            } else {
              // The drawer is closed, so open it.
              scaffoldState.openDrawer();
            }
          },
          child: open ? Icon(iconClose) : Icon(iconOpen),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```